# Support for tablets configuration

Tags: android, google-play, screen, tablet

I have made an application which has been tested on the emulator, some 2.2 phones and a 3.1 tablet. The application worked and the graphics were ok. But when I uploaded it on the market (EDIT: Now named Google Play), the support for tablets wasn't enabled, so I went through some solutions and made these changes to my manifest file.

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephone" android:required="false" />
```

I also changed the minSdkVersion and I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

My target API level is 9, but it's not defined in the manifest. Do you think I should add the following line?

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

And my final question: Is this manifest (with or without the targetSdkVersion parameter) ok so that the android market would allow the tablet device to download and install my application or do I need to check anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using features that are not found on tablets (most notably phone-related), you might need to mark those as optional as well.

Comment: I have placed web, phonecall and sms permissions. I don't think that I need to mark those as optional, because the tablets also use sim cards, so I guess I don't have any special features used by phones only.

Comment: Most tablets can't make phone calls, so your app will get filtered out. You need to explicitly declare the features as optional, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering). If, on the other hand, your app is not useful without those features, filtering out incompatible devices is the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll take the proper action for these features, but about the screen support, do you think I have made the correct changes to my manifest file?

Comment: I have also edited my OP with the optional feature setting. But I have a new question now. Could it be THIS feature that had a result my app to be filtered out and not the screen? I can see on my app webpage that the screens supported go from small-xlarge.

Comment: Well, that should cover most screen sizes, so you should be OK. BTW, IIRC, if you target any API higher than 4, you don't need an explicit `<supports-screens>` unless you want to exclude devices.

Comment: I'll erase it then and try uploading again.

Comment: The market mechanism, detected 1 less feature and the list of the supported devices became wider, so it was that feature after all. And it worked immediately after re-uploading my updated .apk file.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set your targetSdkVersion to something >= 11 - that way you get the ActionBar automatically displayed on tablets, for a better L&F integration with other tablet apps. But this depends as well on what kind of app you have - if you want to run fullscreen you don't want the ActionBar.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a fullscreen application, so I'll skip the targetSdkVersion part.